# Does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS have grub 1?

Tags: grub2, grub-legacy

I am confused by the naming of the grub files on Ubuntu 14.04. I see `grub-install` but not `grub2-install`. I see a `/boot/grub/` directory but not `/boot/grub2/`.

However I don't see a `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file (which is typically the case for grub 1)?

Answer (score 0):

My 14.04 UEFI systems have `grub-efi-amd64-bin` version `2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12` installed.

On the bootup menu the title is GNU GRUB 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12